# Fourier sine/cosine transforms of :1) derivatives raised to power & 2)derivatives in exponential

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I need help to solve the Fourier finite sine and cosine transforms:

First, reciprocal of derivative:
$$
F_s\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}\right)= \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}sin(\omega x) dx
$$
$$
F_c\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}\right)= \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}cos(\omega x) dx
$$

Second, exponential of derivative:
$$
F_s\left(e^\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)= \int_{0}^{a}e^\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}sin(\omega x) dx
$$
$$
F_c\left(e^\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)= \int_{0}^{a}e^\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}cos(\omega x) dx
$$

Comment: What is your attempt ?

Comment: I tried to do some substitution but did not get anywhere, it always get more complicated, I get $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$ in the denominator.